# Most Efficient Way to get a Count of IDs Where INT in (Case?) Groups

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have the following query:

```
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT(ID)
        , CAST(FirstDate AS DATE) AS FirstDate
        , CAST(LastDate AS DATE) As LastDate
        , DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstDate, LastDate) AS [Diff]
    FROM
        Table
    GROUP BY 
        ID
        , FirstDate
        , LastDate
```

From here I want to get split the [Diff] in groups and then get the counts i.e. count where [Diff] between 0-9, 10-19, 20-29...

Above query pulls something like :

```
ID |  FirstDate  |  LastDate  | Diff
------------------------------------
1  | 2019-03-31  | 2019-04-01 | 26
2  | 2019-03-31  | 2019-04-01 | 32
3  | 2019-04-01  | 2019-04-01 | 9
4  | 2019-03-31  | 2019-04-01 | 15
5  | 2019-04-01  | 2019-04-01 | 5
```

Looking for this i.e. count of IDs per Diff group

```
0-10 | 11-19 | 20-29
---------------------
  2  |   1   |  2
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make your query a subquery by wrapping another query around it. This outer query will use case staments to group the data. In the case statements, select 1 when in group value range and 0 when not. SUM the CASE statements to get counts.

Like this

```
SELECT
    SUM( CASE WHEN Diff BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) [0_9]
,   SUM( CASE WHEN Diff BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) [10-19]
,   ETC....
  FROM (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT(ID)
        , FirstDate
        , LastDate
        , DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstDate, LastDate) AS [Diff]
    FROM
        Table
    GROUP BY 
        ID
        , FirstDate
        , LastDate
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many groups you have, and a `CASE` statement isn't a viable option, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),FLOOR(((diff+.001)*1.0)/10) *10) + 
        '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(CEILING(((diff+.001)*1.0)/10) *10)-1),
    count(*)
FROM 
    [Table]
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),FLOOR(((diff+.001)*1.0)/10) *10) + 
        '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(CEILING(((diff+.001)*1.0)/10) *10)-1)
```

EDIT: Did this before I saw your edit and desired output. From here you could put it into a temp table then pivot it. I can help you with that if you need.

Below is code to put it in the format you want. You have to mess with the `StartIndex` and `EndIndex` to get your groups right.

```
CREATE table #temp(DiffGroup varchar(15),StartIndex int, EndIndex int,Num int)

insert into #temp 
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(diff/10) *10) +'-' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(CEILING(diff/10) *10)+9) DiffGroup,
    (diff/10) *10 AS StartIndex, 
    (CEILING(diff/10) *10)+9 AS EndIndex,
    count(*) AS Num
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(diff/10) *10) +'-' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(CEILING(diff/10) *10)+9),
    (diff/10) *10,
    (CEILING(diff/10) *10)+9

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DiffGroup) 
            FROM #temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select DiffGroup
                    , Num
                from #temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                    SUM(Num)
                for DiffGroup in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't case statements work? Oh! I see. if you're number of groups are not know. Gotcha. Yes, that could be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` & do conditional aggregation  :

```
select sum(case when diff >= 0 and diff < 10 then 1 else 0 end) as [0-9],
       sum(case when diff >= 10 and diff < 20 then 1 else 0 end) as [10-19],
       sum(case when diff >= 20 and diff < 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [20-29]
from table t cross apply
     ( values (DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstDate, LastDate)) 
     ) tt(diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the group size as a variable and calculate the offsets and count

```
DECLARE @GroupSize INT = 10

SELECT
    GroupCount  = SUM(CountInGroup),
    StartIndex  =( Diff / @GroupSize ) * @GroupSize,
    EndIndex    =(( Diff / @GroupSize ) * @GroupSize ) + @GroupSize
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CountInGroup = COUNT(*)
        ,Diff = DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstDate, LastDate)
    FROM
        YourTable
    GROUP BY
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstDate, LastDate),
        FirstDate,
        LastDate
) AS X
GROUP BY
    Diff / @GroupSize
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make use of the [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (CTE), then query the CTE to get the desired result. You can create the CTE like below:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        Id,
        [Range] = 
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstDate, LastDate) between 0 and 10 THEN '0-10'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstDate, LastDate) between 11 and 19 THEN '11-19'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstDate, LastDate) between 20 and 32 THEN '20-32'
        END
    FROM
        Table
)
```

You can write the `GROUP BY` query straight after the CTE to get the count of the Diff ranges.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) Count, Range FROM CTE GROUP BY Range
```

The above will produce the output like below:

```
Count   Range
2       0-10
1       11-19
2       20-32
```

If you need the pivoted output like you mentioned in the question, use the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) function straight after the CTE

```
SELECT 'Count' AS Diff,  
    [0-10],  
    [11-19],  
    [20-32]
FROM  
    (SELECT [Range], Id FROM CTE) AS SourceTable
PIVOT  
(  
    COUNT(Id)
FOR   
    [Range] IN ([0-10],[11-19],[20-32])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

You will get the following output

```
Diff    0-10    11-19   20-32
Count   2       1       2
```

I hope this helps